# If you click the "Log Out" link while on the /users/logout page the "cancel" link links to the /users/logout page

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks

This is a silly edge-case that doesn't make much sense, and I may be the only person who has clicked on the "Log Out" link while on the "Log Out" page, but I think the "cancel" link in this case should link to the home page.

Now, If you already keep a recent history of visited pages for the user in memory, perhaps the most recent page that wasn't the "Log Out" page should be used instead of the `referer` header.

Or you could just link to a Google search for [recursion](https://www.google.com/search?q=recursion). :-p

Comment: What made you do such thing in the first place? ;)

Comment: I'm implementing this very thing right now, and was wondering what StackOverflow did. But I'm thinking about replacing the word "cancel" with "recurse" in my case, if I can get approval for it from my boss.

Answer (score 4):

Logout link on the Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ will not longer appear if you are on the logout page.

- Base case of recursion: found
- Bug: [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

To be seen in the next build.